# How do I fill out fillable PDF Form fields using 4gl?

Tags: pdf, progress-4gl, 4gl

I have a PDF form that I'm filling out with data using progress-4gl. To date, I've been only filling in text fields using the following syntax:

```
 put stream stream1 unform
"^global CHX_SINGLE_CE_PLAN3"               skip(0)
"X"                                         skip
```

CHX_SINGLE_CE_PLAN3 is the field name...

This code works when dealing with text fields but I'm trying to check a box instead of fill in a text field.  I cannot find any documentation on this.  Is checking a box on a fillable pdf form even possible with 4gl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the answer, which I thought I had already tried before asking this question.  The answer is you need to pass the value "Yes" (with capital "Y") in order to check the checkbox.  The correct code in this instance is:

```
put stream stream1 unform
"^global CHX_SINGLE_CE_PLAN3"               skip(0)
"Yes"                                       skip
```

I believe this is the case no matter which language you're using

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember PDF Include has support for filling fillable forms. Whilst it's probably a bit over the top in terms of what you want to achieve, it's an open source project and so you may well find the answer to your question within the code itself. 
Here's a link to the project page: http://www.oehive.org/pdfinclude

Comment: thanks jdpjamesp, I've looked at that site but couldn't find what I was looking for... I'm uncertain what parameter I need to pass Adobe in order to get the checkbox checked.